# Find Graphql Resolver name/path without executing the Resolver for the Query

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

We're using graphene for the graphql APIs, here we have a use case to get the resolver name/path which the graphene will execute when we call the API with a specific Query.

We can make use of `schema.graphql`, Query, and Variables, for this.

Can we get the Resolver without executing the query, or any other non-graphene approaches to do this

Comment: Unclear what you're asking - are you trying to figure out what code will execute when a query is called?

Comment: @MichelFloyd yeah, I need to know which method (resolver) in my app, it gonna invoke.